# Parsing JSONP data with AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsonp

Tomorrow I have an exam on Web Design and I can't seem to understand how to read JSONP responses with AJAX. I can do fine with JSON, as well as with JSONP as long as there is no callback function, but when the callback function has a name nothing seems to work.

I will give two examples of this:

**FIRST EXAMPLE**

Reading data from this link: https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN%3A0451526538&callback=mycallback

My function:

```html
$.ajax({
        url: "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:0451526538&callback=mycallback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data){
            var isbn = data["ISBN:0451526538"].bib_key;
                alert(isbn);

        }
    });
```

**SECOND EXAMPLE**

And this one I can't seem to understand WHY it does/doesn't work.

My way (which doesn't work):

```html
$.ajax({
        url: "http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=flowers&format=json#",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.title);
    }
    });
```

Correct code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
$.ajax({
            url: "http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=flowers&format=json#",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "jsoncallback",
            success: function(data){
                alert(data.title);
        }
        });
```

Can anyone PLEASE take the time to explain how I can get past the wrapper (padding) that is the callback function to access the data. Please no $.getJSONP, this is the only way I have to get this to work that will be accepted in my exam.

Answer (score 0):

The jsonp parameter is `jsoncallback`

```
http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=flowers&format=json&jsoncallback=?
```

Comment: But how do I find this out if only the URL is given?

Comment: Read the documentation for the services?

Comment: We have restricted access to the Internet while the exam is ongoing, so the data will load but I can't google anything. And for the first example, is there a way I can get a response that is other than mycallback({...}), i.e. a response with no padding?

Comment: If they do not support CORS than you need to use JSONP and if they do not use callback, than you have to use whatever the parameter is that the service uses. I sure hope your professor tells you what the parameter is.

Comment: So there is no way that I can guess the callback by only looking at the response?